# Bulk API getUpdated contacts

Tags: bulk-api

Is there a way to get updated contacts from salesforce with Bulk API. With SOAP API I can write it like this:

```
SforceService binding;   
// login ....
binding.getUpdated("Contact", startDate, endDate);
```

How can be the same accomplished with Bulk API. For now I am writing SOQL queries. Like this:

```
SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact
```

Is there any field in Contact like startDate and endDate? Does Bulk API even support this?

Comment: i think in query you can use createdDate and ModifiedDate to find the updated records with some basic logic .

Comment: There is CreatedData and LastModifiedDate yes. I found this by running method describeSObjects() -> http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm Thank you Kumar.

Comment: I also wanted to get deleted contacts which I tried with this query: SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE but it does not work. Only with SOAP API binding.getDeleted("contact", startDate, endDate); it works. I guess Bulk API is not developed for this kind of things. Any ideas on this topic?

Comment: Use ALL ROWS at end of query   SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS

Comment: It says: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: MALFORMED_QUERY: ALL ROWS not allowed in this context

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4020/whats-the-actual-meaning-of-all-rows-in-soql                                          can you follow this .I also doubt we are dead in water as ALL ROWS may not be applicable for bulk api

Comment: If you're trying to perform replication, use the replication API (`getUpdated` and `getDeleted`). That's what those APIs are for.

Comment: API getUpdated() and getDeleted() is available only in SOAP API, not in Bulk API. As far as I know in bulk api you can write queries SOQL or insert, update records in salesforce account. So bulk api has somehow limited focused usage. We wanted to use bulk api because of potentially large data that is being transfered. Also to minimize api calls which are limited to 5000 per 24 hours. But again I do not really see advantages of bulk api over soap api.